# Is there a troop I should upgrade first?

Tags: boom-beach

Is there a specific troop which is worth upgrading first in my arsenal?

I'm Level 37, HQ 16, I play with all the troops, but most of the time, for PvP, I use Tank Medic or full Warrior. Sometimes RZM..

Comment: Opinion based question. If you are best at using warriors, you upgrade them first. If you are better at playing safe with tanks, you upgrade those.

Comment: You're right, this is opinion based :/ But I was asking if there was a troop that we need to upgrade first because this is the best :D
If there isn't, sorry for my bad question !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically all popular troops (and combos) are good even for later levels except Riflemen and the Rifleman-Zooka combo, because of 3 rocket launchers and 3-4 Mortars. I didn't try it but I head, even RZM has problems.

**I suggest:**
Chose one troop and max it. After you did that, you can upgrade another troop/combo. I do it like that successfully. The armory and my warriors are on the max limit and now I'm going after the other things (Medkit first, because that benefits Warriors) until I reach another HQ level.

---

I used TMed (Tank-Medic) a lot, but now only as secondary troop. I decided to push my Warriors and I have currently maxed them for my level.

**Pros:**

- Cheap to upgrade compared to other combos (like Tmeds).
- Tmeds need 2 troops upgraded, Warriors only one.
- No matter the level of the enemy defenses, you use shock and smoke. A shocked lvl1 Machine Gun will do the same damage as a shocked lvl20 Machine Gun, zero!
- High-level players use that troop to, so it cannot be too bad.
- Short retrain time.
- You are welcome in Task Force operations. Warriors need to take out key defenses and you normally always have an important thing to do. :)

**Cons:**

- You mostly have to retrain some troops after every battle.
- Killing NPC bases is normally way more comfortable with Tmeds, since you can steamroll 90% of them easily.
- It's a bit harder to play than Tmeds, since you need better reflexes.

Comment: Thanks for full answer :)
I agree with you, Warriors are cheaper, faster, stronger (can beat guys who are 5 level more mine). I'm HQ 16, level 37, and Warrios level 7 (little delay my arsenal is 11 it could be 14 I guess). But I have the red statues (attack & defense) at 30% each. And I try to max my gunboat energy, because if the HQ ennmy is in a corner, with smoke/flare energy cost, I can only throw one shock..

Comment: Your armory can always be as high as the HQ. HQ16 = Armory 16. Like you, I didn't focus on the armory at the beginning. Now, the armory is the MOST important building next to the sculptor. The Armory should run 24/7 and you should only spend gold for clouds (Radar) if you have too much while your Armory is still upgrading something. Cheers :)

Comment: My armory is always running :D
But I have to find a way to make a lot of golds, because warriors and Tanks cost a lot now !
Sculptor is lvl 5, upgrade is very expensive compared to my level, but I know I should do it :/